# How to authenticate my own provider( only for testing purposes)

Tags: java, jce

Now, I wrote a new provider (ESMJCE provider), and I also write a simple application to test it, but I have some exceptions like that

```
java.lang.SecurityException: JCE cannot authenticate the provider ESMJCE
at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(DashoA13*..)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(DashoA13*..)
at testprovider.main(testprovider.java:27)
Caused by: java.util.jar.JarException: Cannot parse file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre1.6.0_02/lib/ext/abc.jar
at javax.crypto.SunJCE_c.a(DashoA13*..)
at javax.crypto.SunJCE_b.b(DashoA13*..)
at javax.crypto.SunJCE_b.a(DashoA13*..)
... 3 more
```

And here is my source code

```
import java.security.Provider;
import java.security.Security;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import esm.jce.provider.ESMProvider;

public class testprovider {

/
@param args
/
public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  ESMProvider esmprovider = new esm.jce.provider.ESMProvider();

  Security.insertProviderAt(esmprovider,2);

  Provider[] temp = Security.getProviders();
  for (int i= 0; i<temp.length; i++){
    System.out.println("Providers: " temp[i].getName());
  }
  try{
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES", "ESMJCE");
    System.out.println("Cipher: " cipher);
    int blockSize= cipher.getBlockSize();
    System.out.println("blockSize= " + blockSize);
  }catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
  } 
}
}
```

Please help me solve this issue

Thanks

Comment: a) What is the output from "Provider[] temp = Security.getProviders();"
b) what is abc.jar in your ext-folder?

Comment: It output all the JCE provider plus my provider

Answer (score 1):

actually you can bypass the Sun-rooted certificate requirement and can sign provider by your own: [Java HotSpot Cryptographic Provider signature verification issue](http://java.zacheusz.eu/provider-signature-verif-vuln-2/273/). And of course look here before: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/HowToImplAProvider.html#Step61

Answer (score 0):

No you can't authenticate it unless you write your own JVM. Otherwise request the JVM provider(Oracle) to sign your Jars.